# rsync --include-from not working

Tags: backup, rsync

The man pages do not have examples for this. I am having a hard time telling rsync to only include some file where those files. I don't understand why you have to exclude in order to include, why the `rsync` just not include what ever is in the include file and that it, everything else will be excluded.

This is my script:

```
rsync -ruv --rsh=ssh --include-from=zz-rsync-test.prod.incl /usr2/subdir remoteSrv:/tmp/.
```

and this is my include file which does not work: It copies too much: it copies every thing in the /usr2/subdir (including the `subdir` directory, weird) which I don't want. I want to copy only those per, 42f, and xml files in the `data/text_forms` directory.

```
+ data/text_forms/*.per
+ data/text_forms/*.42f
+ data/text_forms/*.xml
+ data/text_forms/*.xml.*
```

and the following does not work, it does not copy anything:

```
- *
+ data/text_forms/*.per
+ data/text_forms/*.42f
+ data/text_forms/*.xml
+ data/text_forms/*.xml.*
```

and the following does not work either, it does not copy anything:

```
- *
+ data/
+ data/text_forms/*.per
+ data/text_forms/*.42f
+ data/text_forms/*.xml
+ data/text_forms/*.xml.*
```

and the following does not work either, it does not copy anything:

```
- *
+ data/
+ data/text_forms/
+ data/text_forms/*.per
+ data/text_forms/*.42f
+ data/text_forms/*.xml
+ data/text_forms/*.xml.*
```

The following does not work either:

```
+ */
+ /data/text_forms/*.per
+ /data/text_forms/*.42f
+ /data/text_forms/*.xml
+ /data/text_forms/*.xml.*
- *
```

Neither the following works:

```
+ /data/
+ /data/text_forms/
+ /data/text_forms/*.per
+ /data/text_forms/*.42f
+ /data/text_forms/*.xml
+ /data/text_forms/*.xml.*
- *
```

Comment: Try **--files-from=/absolute/path/to/zz-rsync-test.prod.incl** and the entries in the zz-rsync-test.prod.incl file should be new line separated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found the solution. I took me two full days to find it. I hope this help you to not spend that much time.

The first problem was that the sub-directory `subdir` in `/usr2/subdir` was included and I did not wanted that whole directory to be included, I just wanted it to be the base directory, so it requires a slash at the end as in `/usr2/subdir/`, so my new command looks like:

```
rsync -ruvv --rsh=ssh --include-from=zz-rsync-test.prod.incl /usr2/subdir/ remoteSrv:/tmp/.
```

Note that I added an extra `v` option in the command line (`-ruvv`) to get more detail of what was excluded or included at the moment of running the command. With the base directory fixed and the extra `v` it was a little easier to built the right include file:

```
+ data/
+ data/text_forms/
+ data/text_forms/*.per
+ data/text_forms/*.42f
+ data/text_forms/*.xml
+ data/text_forms/*.xml.*
- *
```

All the `+` lines have to be placed before the `- *`, specially for directories as I had to explicitly include each directory to scan even if I don't want to get files directly inside those directories. I did a test adding a `data/anyTestFile1` and a `data/text_forms/anyTestFile2` because I was not sure if those where going to be picked up, but they did not, so it is doing what I want.... finally.

Comment: Thanks, had the same problem. Your post helped me a lot :-)

Comment: In case there are arbitrary subdirectories, add `+ */` in the include-file just above `- *`. Otherwise the default exclude pattern causes rsync not to traverse the subdirectories.